# How to handleSubmit with a redux-form

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-form

I'm working to use redux-form for the first time. I am able to render the form but I have not been able to handle the submit. While I eventually want to send the data to the server, at this point, I'm simply trying to console log the form field values. I'm getting the error:

`Error: You must either pass handleSubmit() an onSubmit function or pass onSubmit as a prop`

Here's my Profile.jsx file

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {connect} from 'react-redux';
import {withAuth} from 'react-devise';
import { Field, reduxForm } from 'redux-form';

class Profile extends Component {
  handleSubmit(data) {
     console.log('Submission received!', data);
   }
  render() {
    const { handleSubmit } = this.props;
    return (
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
        <div>
          <label htmlFor="firstName">First Name</label>
          <Field name="firstName" component="input" type="text"/>
        </div>
        <div>
          <label htmlFor="lastName">Last Name</label>
          <Field name="lastName" component="input" type="text"/>
        </div>
        <div>
          <label htmlFor="email">Email</label>
          <Field name="email" component="input" type="email"/>
        </div>
        <button type="submit">Submit</button>
      </form>
    );
  }
}

// Decorate the form component
Profile = reduxForm({
  form: 'profile' // a unique name for this form
})(Profile);


const mapStateToProps = state => {
  return {
    currentUser: state.currentUser
  };
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(withAuth(Profile));
```

How can I handle the submitted values in a way where I can eventually send them to my API?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Redux-Form decorates your component with `handleSubmit` prop. According to docs it's:

> a function meant to be passed to `<form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>` or to
>   `<button onClick={handleSubmit}>`. It will run validation, both sync and
>   async, and, if the form is valid, it will call
>   `this.props.onSubmit(data)` with the contents of the form data.
>
> Optionally, you may also pass your `onSubmit` function to `handleSubmit`
>   which will take the place of the `onSubmit` prop. For example:

So if your component doesn't have `onSubmit` property you have to 'manually' pass your submit handler to `handleSubmit` function. Please try this:

```
<form onSubmit={this.props.handleSubmit(this.handleSubmit.bind(this))}>
```

Please don't confuse your `handleSubmit` method with prop passed from Redux-Form with the same name.

Comment: Thank you, that worked even though I'm still trying to understand why... It does result in a WARNING: `11:13  warning  'handleSubmit' is assigned a value but never used  no-unused-vars` -- any idea why the warning?

Answer (score 0):

*(Posted solution on behalf of the question author to move it to the answer space)*.

Working code:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {connect} from 'react-redux';
import {withAuth} from 'react-devise';
import { Field, reduxForm } from 'redux-form';

class Profile extends Component {
  handleSubmit(data) {
     console.log('Submission received!', data);
   }
  render() {
    return (
      <form onSubmit={this.props.handleSubmit(this.handleSubmit.bind(this))}>
        <div>
          <label htmlFor="firstName">First Name</label>
          <Field name="firstName" component="input" type="text"/>
        </div>
        <div>
          <label htmlFor="lastName">Last Name</label>
          <Field name="lastName" component="input" type="text"/>
        </div>
        <div>
          <label htmlFor="email">Email</label>
          <Field name="email" component="input" type="email"/>
        </div>
        <button type="submit">Submit</button>
      </form>
    );
  }
}

// Decorate the form component
Profile = reduxForm({
  form: 'profile' // a unique name for this form
})(Profile);


const mapStateToProps = state => {
  return {
    currentUser: state.currentUser
  };
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(withAuth(Profile));
```